# Handing off to Apple Maps Application from Within Third-Party App in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mapkit

Does anyone know if it's possible to invoke the native Apple Maps application on an iOS 8 device from within a third-party app and pass in the user's `Current Location` (if they give permission) as well as a destination `Latitude and Longitude` to allow the Maps app to plot a route?

I have a relatively simple application which shows an `MKMapView` with various locations plotted on it in a local area. Tapping on one shows an annotation, which in turn allows a modal view to be presented with more information about the premises. I have a "Get Directions" option which I want to simply capture the users location and open up the Maps app with a route calculated from their location to the premises that they've selected without the overhead of having to do it all myself in this app - no budget for handling UI, errors, routing etc (just thought it would be a nice feature if it could be done as simply as handing off to the Maps app).

Any help or advice appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's quite possible, easy, and well documented. Take a look at the MKMapItem class, and the method `openMapsWithItems:launchOptions:` method. If you set up the options correctly it will display driving directions.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Duncan C for pointing me in the right direction. You can actually invoke the maps app using URL schemes and pass in a few parameters but it's also possible through the points giving by Duncan. Here's the full code I ended up with to do exactly what I required.

```
// Check to see if we can use Maps app.
    // Pass an MKMapItem (destination) in along with Current Location
    // Specify what kind of directions we want (driving, Walking etc).
    // Invoke the Maps app.
    Class mapItemClass = [MKMapItem class];
    if (mapItemClass && [mapItemClass respondsToSelector:@selector(openMapsWithItems:launchOptions:)])
    {
        // An MKMapItem which we will pass to Maps app.
        // I'm using properties from my Shop object.
        CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(_shop.coordinate.latitude, _shop.coordinate.longitude);
        MKPlacemark *placemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:coordinate addressDictionary:nil];
        MKMapItem *mapItem = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:placemark];
        [mapItem setName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Branch Name: %@", _shop.branch.name]];
        // Set the directions mode to "Driving"
        NSDictionary *launchOptions = @{MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey : MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving};
        // Get the "Current User Location" MKMapItem
        MKMapItem *currentLocationMapItem = [MKMapItem mapItemForCurrentLocation];
        // Pass the current location and destination map items to the Maps app
        [MKMapItem openMapsWithItems:@[currentLocationMapItem, mapItem] launchOptions:launchOptions];
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Directions Error"
                                                        message:@"Sorry, we've encountered a problem meaning we're unable to provide you with directions at the moment.\n\nPlease use the Call Branch or Text Branch options to get in touch with a representative."
                                                       delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Dmiss"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
```

Comment: Props for reading the docs and doing the work, and for posting the code to benefit others. (voted.) I was afraid I was going to get a "can you post the code" (a.k.a. do the work for me) response to my answer. Yes, you can do it with an URL scheme as well, but the MKMapItem is cleaner and offers more control.

Comment: I never ask for full code Duncan. No benefit whatsoever in that; it's all about getting to the right place to find what you need. Just needed a nudge in the right direction from you. Thanks again.